# Bluetooth 4.0 LE -- Conceptual -- Sending data form master to peripheral AND from peripheral to master

Tags: bluetooth, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

In Bluetooth, specifically 4.0 LE (if this changes anything), what is the way to send data both ways, from master to slave and from slave to master?

What kind of protocol is it better to design? Can you please provide an example of an application level protocol that is typically used in this scenario?

In this case, should the peripheral run two services, one used for sending data to the device and another to receive data from the device? (The "device" is the peripheral/slave).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most forward way of doing this would be to define a custom service which defines the data types and fields and access you need as characteristics, and implement this on both the peripheral and central. If you are looking for a symmetric system, you can implement the same service on both sides. If there is differences in how the two devices access/send data, you can implement two different services, suiting your needs. Either way, you will need both the slave and master peripherals to support both GATT server and GATT client.

Depending on what you want to do, you could either push data using notifications (unconfirmed, you may miss updates on the receiving side) or indications (confirmed, the receiving side will have to acknowledge the push), or you could pull the data using read commands. You could also combine these in various ways, and you could implement access to different data in different ways in your service(s).

I recommend taking a look at the different Bluetooth Low Energy vendors' dev kits and APIs, as well as the different phone/tablet APIs and examples, depending on which platform you aim to develop on/ are familiar with.